# mysql update query to keep same value for duplicate record and increment value for new record

Tags: mysql

I have a table with already filled some data. In that table I have a column called package_code. This column value is not unique. Having some duplicate values and some new values etc. And I have another column package_id. I need  update package_id value based on the package_code. For example package_code is 001234 then package_id is 1. If we have 10 rows with 001234 then package_id is 1. When ever we have package_code 004589 then package_id will be 2 and so on. This update will happen based on a column called sim_id. Below is my table data.

```
id package_id package_code sim_id
1             001234       40025
2             001234       40025
3             001234       40025
4             001200       40026
5             001240       40027
6             001240       40027
7             001275       40088
8             001275       40088
```

My desired output will be:

```
id package_id package_code sim_id
1      1       001234       40025
2      1       001234       40025
3      1       001234       40025
4      2       001200       40026
5      3       001240       40027
6      3       001240       40027
7      4       001275       40088
8      5       001275       40088
```

How can I achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is the query I tried to use.

```
update line_items set package_id = 1 where package_code HAVING count(*)>1 and sim_id = 40025
```

Comment: The point of SO is to **help** you to find a solution to a question, not to do the entire work from scratch instead of you. Pls share what you have tried so far (include your code) to solve your question and what went wrong with it.

Comment: @Shadow I agree...but I doubt the OP would even know where to begin on this one.

Comment: dynamically I will get sim_id value.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if the OP does not even know where to begin, then he needs a developer, not SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using a more versatile database such as SQL Server, we could just assign a rank inside a CTE of your table, and then directly update that CTE.  But you are using MySQL, so the problem becomes harder.

One approach is to generate the `package_id` values off the following table:

```
id package_id package_code
1             001234
4             001200
5             001240
7             001275
```

This table can easily be generated by grouping by the `package_code` and then taking the min `id` value.  Appreciate that the following query on the above table will generate the `package_id` values we want:

```
SELECT package_code,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.id <= t1.id) package_id
FROM table t1;
```

We can join to a table using this logic, and then update the `package_id` values:

```
UPDATE yourTable a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        package_code,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT package_code, MIN(id) AS id
                               FROM yourTable
                               GROUP BY package_code) t2
         WHERE t2.id <= t1.id) AS rn
    FROM
    (
        SELECT package_code, MIN(id) AS id
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY package_code
    ) t1
) b
    ON a.package_code = b.package_code
SET package_id = b.rn;
```

Comment: Excellent, this is what exactly I want. Thank you very much. For me definitely it will take ages, because I am very new to php , mysql thing...

Comment: @VenkatNaidu Happy to help you out.  By the way, I answered this on a cell phone.